# Obtener coordenada actual y setearlo en un text y que no varie (Que muestre la que tomo en ese momento) Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Buenos dias:
Tengo el siguiente codigo que arma un mapa y pone dos puntos sobre el mismo punto A Inicio de recorrido lo escribi yo en la variable, punto B Fin de recorrido lo traigo de la base de datos y lo paso desde un activity anterior por un putExtra. Por ultimo entre ambos puntos trazo la ruta.
Lo que necesito es que el punto de inicio sea mi ubicacion actual ya sea coordenadas o direccion, cualquiera de las dos.
Probe obteniendo las coordenadas y me muestra los dos puntos, pasa que las coordenadas quedan como en un cache (supongo) porque no importa a donde vaya y vuelva a abrir el mapa siempre el origen es la direccion que tomo la primera vez cuando lo probe (No necesito que se actualice constantemente necesito que cuando de click en el activity anterior VER MAPA entre a este activity y me muestre la ubicacion actual como punto de ORIGEN).
Luego probe que las coordenas vayan cambiando y lo logre pero como cambia contantemente la ubicacion del gps el mapa queda cargando porque las coordenadas de ORIGEN van cambiando a cada rato.
Esa es la explicacion.
Mi pregunta es como meto mi ubicacion actual en esta linea:

```
etOrigin.setText("ACA VA MI POSICION ACTUAL, COORDENADAS, DIRECCION,     CUALQUIER FORMATO");
```

Tengo que generarlo en la pagina anterior y pasarlo con un inutExtra? O puedo generarlo en el mismo activity del mapa y que cada vez que lo abra me setee en etOrigen la coordenada que tomo en ese tiempo sin cambiar para que el mapa cargue bien?

Aca va el codigo del MapsActivity:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private EditText etOrigin;
private EditText etDestination;
private List<Marker>originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Marker>destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Polyline>polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private String p = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


etOrigin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
etDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);



Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


    if (extras != null) {
p = extras.getString("direccion");
etDestination.setText(p);
}
etOrigin.setText("ACA VA MI POSICION ACTUAL, COORDENADAS, DIRECCION,     CUALQUIER FORMATO");

sendRequest();
}
private void sendRequest() {

    String origin = etOrigin.getText().toString();
String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();

        if (origin.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor ponga una dirección de inicio",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
}
if (destination.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor ponga una dirección de destino", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
}

try {
new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destination).execute();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
    }

@Override

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED     && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// TODO: Consider calling
return;
}
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public void onDirectionFinderStart() {
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Por favor espere...",
"Buscando las direcciones...", true);

// SI ALGUNO DE LOS CAMPOS ESTA VACIO NO LLEGA AL MENSAJE
    // SOLO REMUEVE LOS MARKETS Y REINICIA

if (originMarkers != null) {
for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
}
    }

if (destinationMarkers != null) {
for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
}
    }

if (polylinePaths != null) {
for (Polyline polyline:polylinePaths ) {
            polyline.remove();
}
        }
    }

@Override
public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
progressDialog.dismiss();
polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Route route : routes) {
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 15));

originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                    .title(route.startAddress)
                    .position(route.startLocation)));
destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                    .title(route.endAddress)
                    .position(route.endLocation)));

PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
geodesic(true).
color(Color.BLUE).
width(10);

            for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
                polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ya solucione lo de pasar la coordenada y el mapa anda ok.
En el activity anterior tengo un text que muestra las coordenadas actualizandose, cuando doy click a ver mapa mando la coordenada por un putExtra al mapa, manda la cordenada del momento en que le di click por lo que el mapa carga ok y muestra el trayecto, si salen y vuelven a entrar manda la de ese momento, q es lo q necesitaba porque no es una pantalla q va a estar siempre abierta es solo por necesidad si no sabe por donde ir.
Lo unico que me falta es esto:
Cuando abro el activity donde esta el boton ver mapa el text tarda de 1 a 3 seg en empezar a cargar las coordenadas, mi problema es que si le dan click al boton antes de q haya cargado la misma, manda al mapa "Textview" y el mapa no se rompe pero no muestra el recorrido porque no estoy pasando las coordenadas de origen. Hay alguna forma de que la carga de la coordenada sea instantanea o de dejar deshabilitado el boton VER MAPA hasta que el textview no sea vacio?

---

Solucionado todo pregunto y me respondo solo jaja

```
         if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 5000);
    } else {
        locationStart();
    }

private void locationStart() {
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
    Local.setMainActivity(this);
    final boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 5000);
        return;
    }
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);


}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationStart();
            return;
        }
    }
}

/* Aqui empieza la Clase Localizacion */
public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
    DetallePendiente mainActivity;

    public DetallePendiente getMainActivity() {
        return mainActivity;
    }

    public void setMainActivity(DetallePendiente mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        // ACA GENERO LA COORDENADA Y LA MUESTRO

        String Text = loc.getLatitude() + "," + loc.getLongitude();
        //Toast.makeText(DetallePendiente.this, Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        origen.setText(Text);

        if(Text != ""){
            btnVerMapa.setEnabled(true);
            btnVerMapa.setText("Ver Mapa");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Y luego inicio el boton VER MAPA deshabilitado y con el texto cargado:

```
  btnVerMapa = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVerMapa);
    btnVerMapa.setEnabled(false);
    btnVerMapa.setText("Cargando...");
```

Y cuando la variable text ya tiene los datos de las coordenadas y no esta vacio hago el if para habilitar el boton y cambiarle el titulo a VER MAPA:

```
String Text = loc.getLatitude() + "," + loc.getLongitude();


        if(Text != ""){
            btnVerMapa.setEnabled(true);
            btnVerMapa.setText("Ver Mapa");
        }
```